# CakePHP 2.7 GoogleChart Plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins

First of all, sorry if I'm asking for help regarding this question but I have been working on this for almost a day now. I searched this site and was able to find a post similar to my question but I cannot get it to work.

Anyway, I am using CakePHP 2.x, and I need to show reports via charts. I saw this plugin for CakePHP [CakePHP GoogleCharts Plugin by Scott Harwell](https://github.com/scottharwell/GoogleCharts). I did everything step-by-step and somehow my views keep on appearing empty. I made sure it wasn't because of conflicting files so I decided to make a new CakePHP project, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Here are my codes:

Controller:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('GoogleCharts', 'GoogleCharts.Lib');

class ChartsController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Student');
    public $helpers = array('GoogleCharts.GoogleCharts');


    public function test_chart(){
        $student= $this->Student->getStudentAges();

        $studentAgesChart= new GoogleCharts();
        $studentAgesChart->type('LineChart');
        $studentAgesChart->options(array('title' => "Student Ages"));
        $studentAgesChart->columns(array(
            //Each column key should correspond to a field in your data array
            'name' => array(
                'type' => 'string',        
                'label' => 'Student Name'
            ),
            'age' => array(
                'type' => 'number',
                'label' => 'Student Age'
            )
        ));

        foreach($student as $row){
            $studentAgesChart->addRow(array('age' => $row['Student']['age'], 'name' => $row['Student']['name']));
        }

        $this->set(compact('studentAgesChart'));
        debug($studentAgesChart);
    }
}
?>
```

View:

```
<div id="chart_div" >
    <?php 
        $this->GoogleCharts->createJsChart($studentAgesChart); 

    ?>
</div>
```

Debug($studentAgesChart):

```
object(GoogleCharts) {
    [private] type => 'LineChart'
    [private] columns => array(
        'name' => array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'label' => 'Student Name'
        ),
        'age' => array(
            'type' => 'number',
            'label' => 'Student Age'
        )
    )
    [private] rows => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            (int) 0 => 'Student 1',
            (int) 1 => '17'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            (int) 0 => 'Student 2',
            (int) 1 => '16'
        )
    )
    [private] options => array(
        'width' => (int) 400,
        'height' => (int) 300,
        'title' => 'Student Ages',
        'titleTextStyle' => array(
            'color' => 'red'
        )
    )
    [private] callbacks => array()
    [private] div => 'chart_div'
}
```

Model:

```
public function getStudentAges(){
        $student_ages = $this->find('all',
            array(
                'order' => array('Student.name' => 'ASC'),
                'limit' => 3,
                'fields' => array(
                    'Student.name',
                    'Student.age'
                )
            )
        );

        return $student_ages;
    }
```

The way I see it, it doesn't contain any errors but my view is empty.

Answer (score 0):

@Scrappy, do you see any output (JavaScript or HTML) included in the DOM when you view source on your page?  Or, is the plugin not generating any content at all?  If you do see JavaScript code added, is your page reporting JS errors in the console that might prevent the chart from loading properly?  If you do not see the JS code, then you likely have not loaded the plugin in your bootstrap file.

Is the page available on the public Internet for review?

The plugin has not seen updates from me in a few years, but there are a few developers that have forked it and updated it for CakePHP 3.0 too.  But, this version should still be working unless something changed on the Google end, which I am sure I would have heard about if that was the case.